# How to remove thin, black line which forms border in pgfgantt

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

How do I remove the box around the tasks in the gantt chart shown in the following code.  How can I then make the bar and group descriptions nice and snug with the tasks?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{times}

\definecolor{teal}{rgb}{0,0.57,0.81}%
\definecolor{aqua}{rgb}{0.51,0.81,0.79}%
\definecolor{blue_gray}{rgb}{0.36,0.52,0.63}%

% create a new command for a ganttbar entry
\newcommand{\ganttbarentryprogresscustom}[5]{%
\ganttbar[progress=#1,%
bar/.append style={pattern color = #2},%
bar progress label anchor=south,%
bar inline label node/.style={above=3pt}]%
{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[%
x unit=1.4cm,%
y unit chart=1.1cm,%
time slot unit=day,%
bar/.append style={pattern=north west lines, pattern color = cyan},%
inline%
]{0}{11}%
\ganttgroup[inline=false]{Task 1}{1}{10}\\%
\ganttbarentryprogresscustom{100}{blue_gray}{Subtask 1}{1}{6}
\ganttbarentryprogresscustom{90}{teal}{Subtask 2}{7}{8}%
\ganttbarentryprogresscustom{75}{aqua}{Subtask 3}{9}{10}%
\end{ganttchart}%
\end{document}%
```

Comment: `bar/.append style={draw=none,pattern color = #2},`? Added `draw=none`. Don't think I quite understand the second part.

Comment: I think what you're proposing adjusts the box around an individual task bar, rather than the box around the Gantt chart.

Comment: Sorry, I clearly misunderstood. `canvas/.append style={draw=none}` then.

Comment: `canvas/.append style={draw=none}` as an option to the `ganttchart` works.  Thanks!  Re-reading my wording, there is some ambiguity.

Comment: The second part of the question refers to the horizontal spacing between the right-justified group name (Task 1 in this example), and the left edge of the canvas.  I'd like to reduce this space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame around the entire diagram is drawn by the `canvas` node, and to remove it you add

```
canvas/.append style={draw=none}
```

to the `ganttchart` environment options.

For the second part, the reason there is so much space between the task 1 label and task bar itself, is that the diagram spans the region 0 to 11, while your task spans 1 to 10. Hence, there is one unit of empty space on the left side. If you add `group label node/.append style={draw}`, and you don't remove the canvas frame, you'll see that there is no space between that node and the canvas node.

There is a little bit of space between the text and the node border, which you can remove with `group label node/.append style={inner sep=0}`. But I'm wondering whether you actually want `\begin{ganttchart}[...]{1}{11}` instead of `\begin{ganttchart}[...]{0}{11}`.

Comment: By the way, I think the `times` package is considered outdated, and that `newtxtext` (and possibly `newtxmath` if you want math) is recommended instead.

Comment: All great and relevant comments; solution works.  Thanks.